# counting how many times something appears in other part of xml document

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Let's say I have an xml file like this:

```
<root>
 <a><b><c> w </c></b></a>
 <x><y><z> w </z></y></x>
 <x><y><z> w </z></y></x>
```

and an xsl line like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/root">
     <xsl:value-of select="count( ./a/b[c = ./x/y/z] )"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And result is 0 (I want it to be 2:)

This is just a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. Basically I want to count how many times stuff from 'a/b/c' appears in some other part of document and as you can see, I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple and short solution that uses the full power of XSLT. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm familiar with XSLT 1.0; but there's two things I see here that are off:

- You're counting "c"'s that match some criterium; but there's only one c - you want to be counting "z"s.
- You're evaluating `./x/y/z/` in the context of *b*, not in the context of *root* - so that xpath isn't doing what you expect.

In XSLT 1.0 (and probably without much ado in 2.0, then):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/root">
     <xsl:variable name="self" select="."/>
     <xsl:value-of select="count(x/y/z[. = $self/a/b/c] )"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In your real code, it'd probably be clearer not to define a variable pointing to `/root` but storing the string you're looking for directly: `<xsl:variable name="val" select="a/b/c"/>`; either way can work.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
/*/x/y/z[. = current()/a/b/c]
```

**This means**:

Select all `/*/x/y/z` elements whose string value is equal to the string value of (one of) the `current()/a/b/c` elements.

**Note** that the standard XSLT function [**`current()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-current) evaluates to the current node (the one for which the template has been selected, or the one on which the body of an `<xsl:for-each>` is being applied.

Comment: +1 Yes, this is the perfect example for `current()` XSLT function.